# Metric to evaluate accuracy of time series decomposition?

Tags: time-series, accuracy, seasonality, decomposition

I am trying to de-seasonalize a large number of business sales data. They all come from the same industry and follow idiosyncratic seasonality patterns. The number of businesses is quite large, and I am looking for a metric that can tell me if I've effectively deseasonalized an individual restaurant.

Decomposition methods such as STL assume:

$y_t=S_t + T_t + R_t$

where $y$ is the data, $S$ is the seasonal component, $T$ is the trend component and $R$ is the remainder.

My instinct is a simple metric $\frac{Var(R_t)}{Var(y_t)}$ to see how much of the variance of the original data was explained. A large value (closer to 1) suggests that the model has not successfully decomposed it.

Is there an academically or industry accepted practice in measuring effective seasonality aside from the "eyeball test"? I have not found any in Hyndman's Forecasting textbook. If not, does my metric make sense intuitively?

Answer (score 0):

It is always hard to prove a negative, but I do not know of such a metric, and I think I am reasonably knowledgeable in time series analysis and forecasting. (Plus, nobody has answered here for five years - if anyone does have a better answer, I would be quite interested.)

The key problem is of course that the seasonal component, like all the other components, is unobservable. Essentially, your question is similar to asking for a metric for how far the parameter estimates in an OLS model are away from the true parameters. We don't know.

The simple metric you propose runs up against exactly this issue. A high value may mean that we have successfully extracted a strong seasonal component - or that we have overfitted the seasonality. And there is no way to know either way. (I have had issues with spikes in retail sales, which presumably come from unmodeled promotions, being interpreted by the model as seasonality, simply because a seasonal model yielded a better in-sample fit, although it was completely spurious.)

Of course, the proof of the model is in the forecasting. So one possibility would be to fit a seasonal and a nonseasonal model, and forecast both out into a holdout set. If the seasonal model yields better forecasts, that is an argument that there is seasonality in the data, and that we have successfully addressed it.